Display product titles as kewords from WooCommerce product category archives
I would like to get product names from WooCommerce product category archive pages to use them as keywords in an HTML head meta tag.
Here is my code:
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php
if( is_product_category() ){
    foreach ($loop_items as $item);
    $kewords .= ','. $product->get_name();
echo $kewords;
} else
    $key = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'keywords', true);
    if( ! empty( $key )  ){
        $meta_key = esc_html($key);
        echo  $meta_key ;
}
?>"/>


You need to loop through WP_Query posts to display product titles  as keywords like:
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php
if( is_product_category() ){
    global $wp_query;

    if ( isset($wp_query->posts) ) {
        $post_titles = array(); // Initializing

        // Loop through product post
        foreach ($wp_query->posts as $post) {
            $post_titles[] = $post->post_title;
        }
        // Display the array as a comma separated string of product titles
        echo implode(',', $post_titles); 
    }
} else
    $key = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'keywords', true);
    if( ! empty( $key )  ){
        $meta_key = esc_html($key);
        echo  $meta_key ;
}
?>"/>

It should work.
